# How can I create Git-style subcommands with oclif?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, oclif

I'm writing a CLI using Heroku's CLI framework oclif. It works great, but I would like to have Git-like subcommands, something like that:

```
$ mycli mycommand subcommand

$ mycli mycommand subcommand --flags="are awesome"

$ mycli mycommand another-subcommand --name="John Doe"
```

I've gone through the docs but I couldn't find any information related to command structure, layout, hierarchy, etc. I could write `mycommand` as a normal command and have a switch on argv's first argument, but my subcommands accept different flags, so I lose oclif's ability to report some help when someone runs `mycli help mycommand`.

So, my question is: **what is the best way to create subcommands using oclif?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following structure:

```
 - src
 --- commands // all your commands will be on this folder
 ----- subcommand1 // if you have more commands from after subcomand1 include them in this folder like the one bellow.
 ------ command.js // a simple command
 ----- subcommand2.js
```

This would produce commands like:

```
cli subcommand1 command --some-flag --some-argument="xpto"
cli subcommand2 --some-other-flag --some-other-argument="WAT"
```

One thing that I've noticed is that if you want to share some flags or arguments with other commands you either will have to use a base class for that or declare the flags/switches/arguments on another file and import them on the desired command